# CheckButtons in diferent frames activating together in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Today I found a issue in python 3.
When creating a checkbutton object in tkinter with different frames, I notice that there is a bug in the gui.
example:

```
root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack()
Checkbutton(frame1).pack()

Checkbutton(frame2).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now the issue here is that if you click on any of the checkbuttons you will find that the other deactivate itself.

Has any of you guys found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbuttons are independent you should associate them to different vars like

```
var1 = BooleanVar()
c1 = Checkbutton(frame1)
c1['variable'] = var1

var2 = BooleanVar()
c2 = Checkbutton(frame2)
c2['variable'] = var2

c1.pack()
c2.pack()
```

and it should work as expected. Because you haven't associated any they are sharing the same entity.

Comment: That is true. It seems that they change the definition in python3 because in python 2 this was not a problem.